# ?_escaped_fragment_= - headless browser

Tags: ajax, hash, web-crawler, headless-browser

what do I have to do to add a `?_escaped_fragment_=` support to my server? I want google to be able to crawl through my ajax site. My hashes are already in `#!` form

But I have no idea how to tell my server that when I enter `mywebsite.com/?_escaped_fragment_=section` to my browser so the url `mywebsite.com/section` and it would be equal to `mywebsite.com/#!`

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple answer - my method (soon to be used for a site with ca. 50,000 AJAX-generated URLs) is to have a node.js server using a headless environment (try zombie, phantomjs, or any other) to load the site, making sure it's able to execute javascript and read the DOM - then at runtime, if it's google requesting the fragment, fire a request to the node.js server, which loads the site, executes the javascript, waits for the response, and delivers back the HTML, which is output to the browser.

If that sounds like a lot of work - I'm about 90% finished on the code that does it all for you, where you'd simply drop one line of (PHP) code at the top of your site/app and it does the rest for you, using a remote node.js server.

The code will be open source so if you want to set it up yourself on a node server, you can - or if it's a PITA to set it up yourself, I'll probably have a live server up and running which your app/website would fire `?_escaped_fragment_` requests to, and get the html snapshot back. It also implements caching so that these are only requested once every X days.

Watch this space - just got a few kinks to work out, and it'll be on my site (josscrowcroft.com) and I'll put it in a github repo too.

Comment: ok, so if I understand, the first thing I need is node.js server. thanks a lot. and then I will wait till you publish your code to github...

Comment: Yeah - starting next week I'll be testing it on a client's site on a rackspace virtual server, so once it's been tested in the wild and I've checked out what kind of load it puts on the server, I'll post up the repo - definitely within a few weeks.

Comment: I was just thinking - what if I use .htaccess to modify the URL. Will it work?